# How to create a Loading UIView while loading data to UIViewConroller Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to figure out the best way to create a loading `UIView` while the data is loaded from the database to the `UIViewController` or loading data to the `UITableViewController`

Something like the following:

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Just search github, there are plenty of different loading views https://github.com/search?q=activity+indicator&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
```

in .h

```
-(UIView *)viewForIndicator
{
    //UIWindow *__autoreleasing win = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
     //UIView *__autoreleasing view = [win.subviews lastObject];
     //return view;

    UIWindow *__autoreleasing win = nil;//[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    NSArray* arrWindows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
    for (UIWindow* w in arrWindows) {
        if ([w isKindOfClass:[UIWindow class]]) {
            win = w;
            break;
        }
    }
    UIView *__autoreleasing view = nil;
    for(int i=(int)[win.subviews count]-1;i>=0;i--){
        view=[win.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if(![view isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]){
            break;
        }
    }
    return view;

}
```

Then use this to show

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:[self viewForIndicator] animated:YES];
```

[Github Link](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Comment: It appears that MBProgressHUD is a third party class (available on Github.) Any time you use third party code in a post, you should state that fact explicitly, along with a link.